# How can i use the fileId of a function for other?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have these two functions but in the id field from the DriveFile, the arquivoiD isn't working, it always return me the error **Drive materials must have an ID."**

```
function uploadFiles(data) {
  var arquivo = data.myFile;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("");
  var subirArquivo = folder.createFile(arquivo);
  var arquivoId = subirArquivo.getId();
  Logger.log(arquivoId)
  return subirArquivo.getUrl(); 
}

function cadastrarAV (nomeAV,curso, arquivoId){//I don't see how you are passing this id in your google.script.run....

var atividade = {
  title: nomeAV.tit ,
  description: nomeAV.desc,
   workType:  "ASSIGNMENT",
 materials: [ {
      driveFile: {//this does not look right...Cooper
      driveFile: { id : arquivoId,
                  title: "Av1"           
            },
         shareMode: "VIEW"
      }
```

Comment: How are you calling cadastrarAV()?

Comment: With this line in the JavaScript page google.script.run.cadastrarAV(nomeAV);

Comment: Do you really have driiveFile twice?

Comment: Well I would combine all of the input parameters into one object.  Or simply use an anonymous function at the handler.  Actually, even if I use an anonymous function I'd still combine them into one object.

Comment: Is uploadFiles server side or clientside?

Comment: It's on server side

Comment: `With this line in the JavaScript page google.script.run.cadastrarAV(nomeAV)` this is your problem your not passing the id here.

Comment: And how can i pass if the id its on a function in the server side?

Comment: Well when you upload files you could have the function return the id to you clientside.